# Multiple-entry visa application for Germany

Tags: visas, schengen, indian-citizens, multiple-entry, schengen-visas

I am an Indian citizen living in London. I have a long-term UK resident permit.

I would like to apply for a multiple-entry Schengen visa, as I am planning to make two trips to Germany to visit my friend. The first is from December 29 to January 6, and the second one is from January 15 to 19.

I am not sure how to fill the intended day of arrival and departure in the application form. Shall I fill the arrival date as December 29 and departure as January 19? (If that's the case, do I need to show money for the whole duration i.e. 20 days?)

How do I mention two separate trips in the application form? I am concerned that if I mention only my first trip, then I might get the visa for that specified duration.

PS: I already have received a Schengen visa in 2015. Any help would be appreciated.